# Highmaps: misplaced +/- when a browser window is narrowed

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am playing Highmaps. I downloaded version 4.2.3 and the first one in its list of examples is called "overview".

When I click this "overview" link, a world map is displayed and the `+/-` is vertically placed on top of the 0-300 scale. However, if I shrink the browser window, the `+/-` changes its position as shown in the picture. This is not right.

Is this a known issue? Anyone knows the fix?

[image]

Comment: This bug is already reported - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4740

Comment: Update: Fix is applied in github version (next release candidate) - example: http://jsfiddle.net/g467d4rp/1/ The problem should be fixed in next Highmaps release.

Comment: Kacper, thanks so much for letting me know the fix. Could you please explain where the fix is made or how to add it to the current version without waiting for the next release? May I know when the next release will be made? Best.

Comment: Turns out that a better fix, not colliding with other features, is need. New releases are usually within few weeks between each other. How to apply a fix before release is explained here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/repo-guidelines.md

Comment: Kacper, is there any fix for this issue at this moment? Thanks!

Comment: No, at this moment no. Stay on track with [the github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4740) to see when new fix will be added.